# Showing that $\Re z \le |\Re z| \le |z|$ and $\Im z \le |\Im z| \le |z|$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

What I'm wanting to show is that $$\Re (z) \le |\Re (z)| \le |z|$$ and also $$\Im(z)\le |\Im(z)| \le |z|$$ So what I've done so far is to consider $$z=x+iy$$ Using the above $z$ I also said that $$\Re (z)=x$$ $$|\Re (z)|=x$$ $$|z|=x+iy$$ It's easy to see that $\Re (z)$ could be either negative or positive, but either way $\Re (z)\le |\Re (z)|$ The problem I'm having is showing mathematically that $$|
\Re (z)|\le |z|$$ It makes senses logically, but I don't know how to go about it mathematically. Am I missing something super basic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $z = x + yi$, then $|\Re(z)| = |x| = \sqrt{x^2} \le \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = |z|$.

Comment: Oh, I see what you did. Rewritting $|x|$ as $\sqrt{x^2}$. Is that something we'll use a lot?

Comment: I don't know what your class covers, but it's something that you should have in your back pocket.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply!